# What is the best way to get diamonds in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I know the Y11 Strip Mine and the Y11 Strip Mine/Poke Hole methods (mining to Y11 and then mining 5 blocks forward and as far as I can reach to the left, right, up and down), but is there any better way?

I am playing version 1.12.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to mine around lava around y coordinates 11. You can find any ore anywhere so long as you're at the right height for it. It just so happens that the level where lava spawns is also the level where diamonds do. Nonetheless, you can find diamonds that aren't near lava. I just found 15 diamond in one trip!

Comment: ok thats for the tip

Comment: I no it’s not the best tip and I hate srip mining I just look for mine shafts at y 11